# My vectors are gone

Tags: 3d-view

I think I pressed a key and now:

- My vector and main grid are gone
- Blender doesn't show me my background image.

How do I fix it?

Comment: Hi. Please add an image to your post to show what you mean. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I am not sure if this will solve your problem but try clicking on the button showed in the image :) That will hide/unhide your overlays (main grid included)